# Log local network traffic into file

Tags: bandwidth

I want to log the receive data speeds of a NIC card in linux into a text file. What is the best way to do something like this (not afraid of using terminal)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then
    echo "You must provide an interface to monitor"
    exit
fi

nic="${1}"
while true; do
    SPEED=$(cat /proc/net/dev | grep $nic |awk '{$1=$1};1' | cut -d' ' -f 2)
    TIME=$(date +%s)
    echo "$TIME,$SPEED" >> /tmp/log-bandwidth-$nic-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
    sleep 5
done
```

If you create this as a file, say `bandwidth-monitor.sh`, then you can run it and provide the network interface to monitor:

```bash
bash bandwidth-monitor.sh eno1
```

This will create a file in `/tmp` (which you can modify.  For example:

```bash
tail -f /tmp/log-bandwidth-eno1-2022-06-03
```